# .Net Framework Templates Missing After Update

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I had visual studio 2019 16.3 and yesterday I did a update to latest version (16.10) and after update all the .net framework templates are gone and only .Net Core are available.

**[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puCZb.jpg)**

**[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8SON.jpg)**

I really need them back because I only work with .net framework and I don't want to manipulate xml stuff to make them work.
How can I get them back?

I even downgrade to the 16.3 again but it was the same.

[Here's a detail of my installation config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7XxY.jpg)

A video that shows individual settings :
https://streamable.com/97fqe9

[And here's templates without using classic dialog extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzLPy.jpg)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2019